# Getting Object in Nested Loop

Tags: c#

I have Nested Loop Object every object contains Id and Name if pass the id as a param needs to get required  name based on Id without using any looping

if any possible to get like that can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
var name =yourList.Where(x=>x.Id=="myId").Name;
```

Comment: Whatever it is "Nested Loop Object" it may be, or may not be, a IQueryable. If it is not a queryable, eg. a List, your answer would be invalid.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but I have Hierarchical loop where the id match I don't know, that is the problem

Comment: Hi Julio, this is my object, for ex:-  I will pass param ID =3  get "C", it is possible without loop in c# 
[
  {
    "Name": "A",
    "ModuleDetailId": 1,
    "Form": {
      "Tabs": [
        {
          "Name": "B",
          "ModuleDetailId": 2,
          "Tabs": [
            {
              "Name": "C",
              "ModuleDetailId": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]

Comment: Please share your code in a  structured way as part of your question.